# fs.writeSync output messy when pass a chinese string?

Tags: node.js

```
fs.writeSync(process.stdout.fd, '输入中文会显示乱码');
// output: 杈撳叆涓枃浼氭樉绀轰贡鐮
```

This problem also see in package: `readline-sync`

How to solve?

Comment: Try with one character, and try with emoji. Is it UTF-8 all the way?

Comment: For what it's worth, that line works on my machine, but I have a UTF-8 terminal.

Comment: @tadman Yes. It output two garbled word after input a single emoji

Comment: @tadman That's weird.